# Can't start engine now. Stuck in neutral but clutch is almost new. Odd burning smell when it last ran. Engine stalled when clutch depressed

Tags: transmission

Almost new clutch. Cant shift out of neutral. Can't start engine anymore. Odd burning smell when it last ran and quit. I was able to restart it once, but when I depressed the clutch, engine slowed down and stalled.

Comment: Is this with an aftermarket clutch? Have you had aftermarket clutches in your car previously? Also, what car is this on?

Comment: Please add the year/make/model. Does the gear selector move freely or not at all?